# Laravel Passing data from page 1 to page2

Tags: ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

Recently, I tried to build my own Laravel system, but I met a huge problem.

I'm using FullCalendar on the page 1 and I want to pass the "date data" to page 2.

However, I can get the "date data" on page 1 which is using jQuery (the variable name is 'selectedDate').

I even tried to use AJAX to pass data to controller

The following is my AJAX code on page1.blade.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'step1getdate',
    type: "get",
    data: {date: selectedDate},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, b, c) {
        console.log("xhr=" + xhr + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
    }
});
```

web.php code is as following

```
Route::get('campustour/step1getdate', 'CampusTourStep1Controller@showDate');
```

CampusTourStep2Controller code is as following

```
public function showDate(Request $request){

        $date = $request->input( 'date' );

        return view('campusTour.step2', compact('date'));
}
```

but I still stuck on the same page and get the Step2 full html code on the console log window. When I checked the $date parameter on the console.log, it's passing data correctly. But what I want to do is return the whole page (step2) not just in the console.log.

Can anyone give me some guidance or keywords and let me keep moving?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You haven't used the response data to get displayed on the page. You have just printed it in the console. It should be something like, jQuery("body").html(data);

Comment: OMG, It worked! Thank you.

Comment: you should not use ajax if you don't need it.. just submit a form instead